# How to prevent package from reloading?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider the following

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
$ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "Combinatorica`"];
```

When I execute it the second time, it's 10 times faster and it doesn't print the compatibility warning.

1. How does Mathematica know this package has been loaded already?
2. What's a good way to avoid reloading the package when it's been loaded and removed from `$ContextPath`?

I'm relying on Combinatorica for some graph algorithms, but I need to redefine `Element` every time it is loaded, so I'm trying to keep reloading to minimum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the usage message for Needs:

> Needs["context`"] loads an appropriate
>   file if the specified context is not
>   already in $Packages.

Are you sharing your code with anyone else, or could you just edit your copy of Combinatorica to not add the problematic definition for Element?  (Should probably verify that Combinatorica isn't using it internally in a way that would cause problems.)

Comment: "Combinatorica" defines Element to work as Part, so I'm expecting there'd be some messages if it relied on that definition. All of the graph theory algorithms in Combinatorica run without error messages. Yes, I'm sharing the code, it relies on Element working like MemberQ, which seemed like a good idea before I knew about Combinatorica's redefinition

Comment: Ah, Combinatorica even says that its use of Element is obsolete, but still works.

Answer (score 2):

1. You probably want to look at `$Packages` variable. The first time you load, your context gets appended to it. The second time, it is not loaded at all, since it is already in `$Packages`, so *nothing* is happening thesecond time (apart from bringing the context back on the `$ContextPath`, but you delete it anyway). You can verify that `Get` is not invoked the second time by using `On[Get]`.
2. Since there is no actual reloading happening the second time, you don't have to do anything. But this also means that *if* you want to really reload the package, you have to first delete its context from `$Packages`, otherwise the call to `Needs` will do nothing except returning your context back on the `$ContextPath`.

Comment: I see, thanks. And I'm guessing "<<somepackage" reloads the package each time without checks?

Comment: @Yaroslav: Correct.  Get (<<) always reloads the file.

Comment: @Yaroslav: I wrote a package a few years ago, called PackageManipulaions`, which does a number of things with packages including reloading and removing. I use it for interactive package development, because it allows clean (I hope) 'hot swap' - reloading a package without ending the session. Anyways, it contains some code which can illustrate this stuff with reloading. It is available at http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/download/packages/PackageManipulations.m